# Stack navigation and connexion

Tags: javascript, react-native, stack-navigator

I'm trying to link the stack navigation with one button, but this button is also the function to add a new register or to connect t the app.

When i click the function to create a new user is working but not the navigation stack (this one is supposed to bring me to the login page)

```
<Button
            title="Suivant"
            style={styles.submitButton}
            onPress={
              (this.addNewRegister,
              () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'))
            }
          />
```